# Matrix generated by prime numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be the vector of dimension $n^2$ consisting of ordered prime numbers
i.e. $p= [ 1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 5 \ 7   \ldots]^T$ and $A$ be the matrix of dimension $n\times{n}$ constructed with this vector by the following way:

- the first  column of $A$ is the first  $n$ prime numbers from 
  vector $v$
- the second column of $A$ is the next   $n$ prime numbers from 
  vector $v$
- etc.

Examples of such matrices:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
2 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &  5 &  13 \\ 
 2 &  7 &  17   \\
 3  & 11 &  19   
   \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &   7 &  19 &  37 \\ 
 2 &  11 &  23 &  41 \\
 3  & 13 &  29 &  43 \\
 5 &  17  & 31 &  47 
\end{bmatrix}$,  $\dots$

**Question:**
is it true that for any $n$ $ \ $ rank$(A)=n$ (i.e. columns of $A$ are linearly independent) or for some $n$ the statement above is not true?

Comment: Usually, the primes start with the number $2$

Comment: Probably, the matrices all have rank $n$, but a proof will be very difficult

Comment: No matter, whether we start with $1$ or $2$, for $1\le n\le 200$ , we get a matrix with rank $n$

Comment: @Peter Thank you Peter for confirmation that the conjecture is true for $n<201$, ...I was also thinking whether to start this vector $p$
from 1 or 2 .. but to the $n=4$ it was satisfied for both cases... and you have confirmed now that it is true up  to the $n=200$.

Comment: If someone kind can confirm conjecture for some greater n>200 please give information here to the other users, I have no tools to operate with such big matrices built from so many primes..

Comment: @Peter, Since you have a code to check this, were you able to check that the determinants are positive and increasing? It would be nice to look for some pattern if there exists any

Comment: @i707107 Yes, it would be very interesting... determinants for small dimensions matrices, I've checked, are also non-zero if we start the vector $p$ not necessary  from the first number,  but  from some  following e.g  3, 7, 11 etc.. but in this case determinants are changing a sign..

Comment: The late result from Robert Israel https://oeis.org/A067276/b067276.txt. ( matrix starts at 2) The number of digits for the determinant seems to increase almost in linear way.

Comment: The log of the absolute values of the determinants $\ln |d(n)|$ seem to agree roughly to $\frac \pi4 \cdot (\ln |d(n)|)^{0.81} \approx n$ using dimension $n$ up to 100 so the growth of the log would rather appear nonlinear.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Very interesting result, how it was found?

Comment: I used Pari/GP and did the matrix-calculations. Then tried some transformations on the values of the determinants and the $n$-(matrixsize) parameter and used Excel to locate some trend. That given estimate was based on values for $n=2$ to $n=100$. Later I found a list of values up to $n=459$ provided by Robert Israel and accessible via OEIS. That indicates a slight adaption to a better formula - didn't look at it as intense as before, but again suggested non-linear connection. Perhaps there is something involved with binomials in the exponent...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Interesting that 0.81 is "almost" equal to $\pi/4$ ..

Comment: @ widawensen: well, sure. But the additional data by R. Israel should be taken into calculation and a better guess for the function should be done. I stepped out after I'd seen, that it is surely non-linear (because linearity was suggested by one earlier comment); after that I tried a handful of types of trends getting that one which pleased me on visual impression. It surely needs some more serious approach with more shapes of the trend-curve...

Comment: Here is an idea I searched on further: https://qr.ae/TJr1AY &  
https://oeis.org/A067276

Comment: @Praskovya2.718281828 Thank you for interesting links :)

Comment: @Widawensen, you're welcome! I was also interested in this problem and I enjoy reading the comment section here, as well (:

Comment: I would perhaps try an alternative method of filling out to higher matrices.  For example there are many ways to fill out that lead to the previous matrix being a submatrix in the upper left corner of the next matrix.  That sets you up to be able to use induction potentially, but the proof is still not pretty.

Comment: 1 isn't a prime number because it only has 1 factor. A prime number must have two factors - 1 and itself.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this conjecture holds but there doesn't appear to be any patterns that help us with computation.

By bruteforcing the determinant, we find that this holds up to n = 459 (based on the following OEIS documentation: https://oeis.org/A067276/b067276.txt). However, the magnitude of determinants between
n = i, i+1 are not necessarily increasing for every such i (e.g. determinant of n = 27 > determinant of n = 28).